# jQuery: .css not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I'm newbie to javascript, actually, it's the first time I have to write something in it on my own.

My problem is that when I try using this script:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
$('.masthead').css({
    'margin-bottom': '-30px',
 });
});
```

It doesn't work at all. What I want to do, is move whole page content after opening submenu. Normally I would do it in css, but in this case, it's some wordpress template, and it's kind of hard to get it all running fine. :/

so:
.masthead is containing whole menu, after some modifications I set margin-bottom to -80px, but now I need it to extend after submenu shows up.

.menu-item-has-children is one of a couple classes I could actually use - it contains menu position that shows submenu after clicking it.

I'm struggling with this for some time now, it would be great if someone could help me :)

SOLUTION:

```
jQuery('.parent-menu').click(function() {
jQuery('.masthead').css({'margin-bottom': '-30px'});
});
```

Comment: use `'margin-bottom':'-=30px'`

Comment: Try substituting `jQuery` for `$` ,  `.css(
    'margin-bottom', '-30px');` for `.css({
    'margin-bottom': '-30px',
 });` Appear to be syntax error at trailing comma `,` after `30px` ?

Comment: I just read somewhere that it won't work in wordpress so I changed each $ to jQuery, console in chrome is clean now, but it still doesn't work :/
Thanks for comment though, @guest271314 :)

Comment: OK, now it works - it actually was the syntax error you told me about ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

U can just use an add_class on your element, and remove it.

Then create a class in css with your custom properties.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() { $('.masthead').css( 'margin-bottom','-30px');
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already found a solution :)

However now I'm struggling with making it -80px again after clicking one more time :/

Comment: do you mean after clicking .masthead class containing element ?

Comment: actually it looks more like this: <div class="masthead"><div id="parent-menu"></div></div> and after I click on parent-menu, the masthead margin-bottom changes, but I'd like it to return to normal after clicking one more time